# Is 's/he' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

When it is needed to refer both male and female with pronoun,we usually use masculine pronoun 'HE'.But nowadays many people claim that it is a form of gender discrimination.So if in this type of case ,I use 's/he'.But can it be called grammatically correct?

Comment: This seems like it is merely asking for opinions... and problematic at best. For instance who is this *we* who usually uses the masculine pronoun for either gender examples?

Comment: That "we" would be the English language for the  past thousand years. The masculine pronouns and the "general" pronouns have always been the same. Even nouns are sometimes-- mankind, the Ascent of Man, etc. So there is your answer. And No, s/he is not just ungrammatical. It is bad English; semi-literate.

Answer (score 1):

It can hardly be called ungrammatical, but it doesn't make for an elegant style. You can either use *they* or recast the sentence.